# Dynamic form input value not hydrated on first submit

Tags: angular, forms, undefined

I have a form made up of ***n*** inputs :

```
    <form class="new-user" [formGroup]="customFields">
      <div *ngFor="let customField of customer['customFields']; let i = index">
          <div *ngIf="isEditing(i)" [@phaseAndSlideLeftAnimation] class="cusomer-property">
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label i18n="getFormKey(customField)">{{getFormKey(customField)}}</mat-label>
                <input
                  ...
                  (keyup.enter)="finalizeEdit(customField, getFormKey(customField))"
                  (keyup.esc)="cancelEdit(customField)">
                <mat-hint align="end">{{input.value?.length || 0}}/{{maxChars}}</mat-hint>
              </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="isNotEditing(i)" [@phaseAndSlideLeftAnimation] class="cusomer-property pointer" (click)="viewEdit(customField)">
              <div>{{getFormKey(customField)}}</div>
              <div>{{getFormValue(customField)}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

and here is my dynamic form init :

```
if(this.customer && this.customer['customFields'].length){
      this.customer['customFields'].forEach((o, i) => {
        if(o['value']){
          this.customFields.addControl(o['name'], new FormControl(o['value'], Validators.required));
        } else {
          this.customer['customFields'][i]['value'] = '';
          this.customFields.addControl(o['name'], new FormControl(o['value'], Validators.required));
        }
      });
    }
```

The bug I'm having is that the first of the fields I click on (that then switches to a mat-forms input via the `*ngIf`) does not have a hydrated field (yet).

Ergo in my pseudo-submit function :

```
  finalizeEdit(customField, key){
    console.log(this.customFields['value'][key]);
    customField['value'] = this.customFields['value'][key];
    this.popCustomFields.next(this.customer);
    this.closeEdit(customField); 
  }
```

`this.customFields['value'][key]` (read:`this.customFields.value.myinput`), returns `undefined`.

...

But If I click and open a second "custom field" or input, all of my inputs now all my values are correctly instantiated in the form and up to speed.

This for, some reason, is for ALL the fields of the form.

You'd think that it's one of those `*ngIf`-related issues but apparently not :
If I reveal one field, then reveal another. Both of them are now ready and every field after that.

So the bug only happens on first "input-ngIf-reveal" after the view is loaded.

I then I found this : https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/forms/submitting-and-resetting/

And found out that you can do this :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  .
  .
  .
</form>
```

The hope is that this function when fired would recieve correctly hydrates values even on first submit...

Since In my case I don't care that the submit is fired over the whole form, this could work for me.

Here's my quandary :

To use this, given that I want to pass `customField` as an argument to `finalizeEdit()`, I'd need to put the start and end of the `<form>` tags in the DOM, inside the `*ngFor` in order to be able to pass it the variables the submit needs.

The problem is this would result in ***n*** Forms of 1 input instead 1 Form of ***n*** inputs and undermining the whole code behind forms.

I feel like that would making my code worse.

Plus I'd have to resort to extracting each Forms to a component to correctly initialize the forms.

All this without a guarantee that this would solve my "first-click" bug.

Ideally I'd be able to put the `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"` on `<input>` instead of on `<form>` but I tried that and it isn't an available method.

And in anycase I suspect form's onSubmit is not the solution to my ills. why aren't my input fields instantiated on first try?

EDIT ( 16 / 07 / 2018 ) :

after trial I can confirm that onSubmit is not a solution as it only fires once and fails to fire at all if two or more fields in a row are opened before initial firering.

Comment: I am sorry to say this but, you can make your question more simpler and shorter so that it is easy to understand your problem.

Comment: okay, maybe I put too much code and repeated myself?  can you point me to the parts that are too long?

Comment: I reduced the size alot and made the context clearer, tell me what part remains unclear if applicable. Just make sure you focus only on the part at the end the part above is just the presentation of the code.

Comment: Can you show the way the `customFields` is being initialized ?

Comment: it's there in the edit history. x) is it shorter or longer you guys want? I'll put it back.

Comment: could you add a https://stackblitz.com/ example? I will help us understand the problem and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `FormBuilder`, `FormGroup` and `FormArray`. I took the liberty to change some things (I omitted components from Material package, and changed the structure of the `customers` data to make my work easier), and implemented what I think will solve your problem.

Here is the [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-51309007) on StackBlitz.

**Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { distinctUntilChanged, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  customer = {
    customFields: [
      { value: 'one', key: 'first', isEditing: false },
      { value: 'two', key: 'second', isEditing: false },
      { value: 'three', key: 'third', isEditing: false },
      { value: 'four', key: 'fourth', isEditing: false }
    ]
  };

  get fields() {
    return this.form.get('fields') as FormArray;
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      fields: this.fb.array([])
    });
    if (this.customer && this.customer.customFields && this.customer.customFields.length) {
      this.customer.customFields.forEach(field => {
        if (!field.value) {
          field.value = '';
        }
        this.fields.push(this.fb.control(field.value, Validators.required));
      });
    }
    this.watchFormChanges();
  }

  saveEdit(index: number) {
    this.customer.customFields[index].value = this.fields.at(index).value;
    this.toggleEdit(index);
  }

  cancelEdit(index: number) {
    this.fields.at(index).setValue(this.customer.customFields[index].value);
    this.toggleEdit(index);
  }

  toggleEdit(index: number) {
    const isEditing = this.customer.customFields[index].isEditing;
    this.customer.customFields[index].isEditing = !this.customer.customFields[index].isEditing;
  }

  private watchFormChanges() {
    this.form.get('fields').valueChanges
      .pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), debounceTime(500))
      .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="fields">
    <div *ngFor="let field of fields.controls; let i=index">

      <ng-container *ngIf="customer.customFields[i].isEditing; then editing else displaying"></ng-container>

      <ng-template #editing>
        <div class="field">
          <label [for]="i">{{ customer?.customFields[i].key }}:</label>
          <input [id]="i" class="value" type="text" [formControlName]="i (keyup.enter)="saveEdit(i)" (keyup.esc)="cancelEdit(i)">
        </div>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #displaying>
        <div class="field">
          <label>{{ customer?.customFields[i].key }}:</label>
          <span class="value" [title]="fields.getRawValue()[i]" (click)="toggleEdit(i)">{{fields.getRawValue()[i]}}</span>
        </div>
      </ng-template>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The biggest part of my problem is that my forms are declared dynamically and contain dynamic elements to be input. here your form is static and you know the element's names and values ahead of time. this doesn't apply to my situation.

Comment: @tatsu I beg to differ, the form array is generated from the `customers` array so if you initialize the form after you get that variable (for example from an API), it's going to generate the form dynamically

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with custom fields.
As I understand it, you are from the first field make a submit. But it turns out that the field has not yet transferred its value to the form. In this situation I was doing a little delay with `setTimeout`.